# Symmetric Matrices: Show that A and B commute.

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I go about this problem? Any help is very much appreciated!

Show that $A$ and $B$ commute if $a-d = 7b$

$$A=\left[ \begin{matrix} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & -5 \end{matrix} \right]$$ $$B=\left[ \begin{matrix} a & b \\ b & d \end{matrix}\right]$$

Answer (score 1):

$$AB=\left[ \begin{matrix} 2a+b & 2b+d \\ a-5b & b-5d \end{matrix}\right]$$

$$BA=\left[ \begin{matrix} 2a+b & a-5b \\ 2b+d & b-5d \end{matrix}\right]$$

As we can see, the only issue here are that in order for them to commute, we need $2b+d=a-5b$.  This is simply $7b+d=a$, or $a-d=7b$, as you were given.

For such problems simply calculating each and seeing what is necessary for them to be equal.